# How to add ID and label tag to checkbox with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have the following HTML code (that I can't access/amend) for one of my many  checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" value="1">
```

I want to turn the checkbox into a toggle, for which I understand I need a `<label>` tag associated with the 'ID' of the checkbox. Unfortunately, the HTML code as per above has only the input tag without `ID` and no `<label>` tag.

To create a checkbox toggle I understand I would need a unique `ID` and associated `<label>` tag for each checkbox such as for example:

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" value="1" ID="checkbox1"> <label for="checkbox1"></label>
```

I have two questions:

- How can I add the `ID` and `<label>` tag with jQuery to my existing `<input>` tag to create a code as per the example?
- Given that I have c. 40-50 checkboxes of which each needs its own `ID` and `label` tag, is there a way to make the jQuery code compact as opposed to copy paste the code 40-50x?

I would much appreciate your help. Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT

```js
<script>
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, v) {
     var checkbox = $(this);
     checkbox.attr("id", ("checkbox_" + (i + 1)))
     checkbox.after($("<label>").attr("for", checkbox.attr("id")));
});
 </script>
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
  <div class="geodir-filter-cat gd-type-single gd-field-fieldset"><span>Header</span>
 <ul>
 <li><input  type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a"  value="1" /> &nbsp;</li>
 <li><input  type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1b"  value="1" /> &nbsp;</li>
 </l>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over each checkbox and add the label after it.

Example:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
     var checkbox = $(this);
     checkbox.after($("<label>").attr("for", checkbox.attr("id")));
});
```

In case your initial `input` doesn't have an id attribute set, then set it manually first:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i, v) {
     $(this).attr("id", ("checkbox_" + i))
     $(this).after($("<label>").attr("for", $(this).attr("id")));
});
```

**EDIT 1:**

Putting this code into `<head>` is not going to work, as the content that this code addressing is not yet loaded at that time. Either put this code before closing `</body>` tag or use ready function.

```
$(function() {
    // code above is here
});
```

Comment: @AlphaX You need to run this code after page finishes loading. Wrap my code into ready function. `$(function() {// .... code is here });`

Comment: Awesome the ready function did the trick! thank you Ilia! The only problem remaining is that the code produces a start with "checkbox_2" so the id and label is always one number ahead which creates code confusion. Is there any easy solution for this? Thousand thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

According your given markup please see below:

```
   $('.cat_input').each(function() {
     var checkbox = $(this);
     checkbox.attr('id', 'checkbox'+checkbox.index()); // Adding ID attribute
     checkbox.after($("<label for='checkbox"+ checkbox.index() +"'>").text(checkbox.val())); // Adding label with for attribute
    });
```

And HTML I assumed like following:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" value="5">
```

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to do it like `<label><input /><span></span></label>` for me I think its simple to use and to style/css it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.cat_input').each(function(i){ // index start from 0
    i = i + 1; 
    $(this).val(i).attr('id' , 'checkbox' + i).wrap('<label></label>').closest('label').append('<span>'+i+'</span>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" />
```

the code for first input will be

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" class="cat_input" name="subcategory1a" value="1" id="checkbox1"/>
  <span>1</span>
</label>
```